# Wordpress get_the_ID() returns 0

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

```php
function post_like(){ 
    global $wpdb;
    $c = $_POST['next']; 
    echo $c; 
    $d = get_the_ID();
    $wpdb->insert('wp_likes',
        array(
            'article_id' => $d,
            'user_id' => '1'
        )
    );
    die(); 
}
```

and my ajax.js file:

```php
function Click_Me() {
    var className = jQuery('#flag').attr('class');
    if (className == "like") {
        var temp = "unlike";
    } else {
        var temp = "like";
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: like.ajax_url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            action: 'post_like',
            next: temp
        },
        success: function() {
            jQuery('#flag').attr('class', temp);
            jQuery('#sonuc').html(temp);
        }
    });
}
```

If I want to get id with this method

```php
$a = get_the_ID();
$a variable's value == 0
```

Why? I tried other tricks for getting id, but methods do not works. I think the problem is ajax but I don't understand why...
Thanks for answers.

Comment: get_the_ID() is to be used in the loop. Why not just pass the ID in the ajax data?

Comment: How can i write this code? In Wordpress Codex documantation, get_the_ID() not to be used in loop.(I am beginner )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user id returns 0, you should be use this metod :  `intval();`

Because during wordpress coding, table type int : %d so it's must be integer.

For Example(Ajax) :

```php
$user_id = intval( $_POST['user_id'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global post and fetch its id.
Like:

```php
global $post;
$d = $post->ID;
```

If you don't want to do it this way.
You can simply pass the id value to ajax data.

Comment: global $post; $d = $post->ID;

When I'm trying this fetch id, database can't insert the data...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function with global $post as an argument.

```php
function post_like($post){ 
    global $wpdb;
    $c = $_POST['next']; 
    echo $c; 
    $d = $post->ID
    $wpdb->insert('wp_likes',
        array(
            'article_id' => $d,
            'user_id' => '1'
        )
    );
    die(); 
}
```